# Oracle sql query to xml

Tags: xml, oracle

I have the below query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PLAYERID, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME, P.POSITION,PT.POINTS, PT.MINUTES, CALC_TENDEX(P.PLAYERID, PT.TEAMID, 2009) TENDEX, T.DIVISION, PT.TEAMID, T.TEAMNAME
FROM PLAYERS P
JOIN PLAYERS_TEAMS PT ON P.PLAYERID = PT.PLAYERID
JOIN TEAMS T ON PT.TEAMID=T.TEAMID
WHERE PT.YEAR=2009 AND T.DIVISION='East'
ORDER BY TENDEX DESC
FETCH FIRST 12 ROWS ONLY;
```

I want to output this query as xml, with custom format like this:

```
<nba dataset="topplayers">
    <division ID="East">
        <player></player>
                .
                .
                .
        <player></player>
</nba>
```

I have tried using SQL/XML but whatever I try does not return answers I want. Is there some easy way to directly convert it to xml?

EDIT: SQL/XML I have tried (along with various alterations of this)

```
SELECT DISTINCT XMLELEMENT("nba",
         XMLAGG (
           XMLELEMENT("division",
             XMLATTRIBUTES(T.DIVISION AS "ID"),
               (SELECT DISTINCT XMLAGG(
               XMLELEMENT("player",
                 XMLFOREST(
                   P.PLAYERID AS "playerid",
                   P.FIRSTNAME AS "firstname",
                   P.LASTNAME AS "lastname",
                   P.POSITION AS "position",
                   PT.POINTS AS "points",
                   PT.MINUTES AS "minutes",
                   CALC_TENDEX(PT.PLAYERID, PT.TEAMID, 2009) AS "tindex",
                   T.DIVISION AS "division",
                   PT.TEAMID AS "teamid",
                   T.TEAMNAME AS "teamname"
                  )
                )
              )
              FROM PLAYERS P
              JOIN PLAYERS_TEAMS PT ON P.PLAYERID = PT.PLAYERID
              JOIN TEAMS T ON PT.TEAMID=T.TEAMID
              WHERE PT.YEAR=2009 AND T.DIVISION='East' AND ROWNUM < 12
            )
          )
        )
       ) AS "nba"
FROM TEAMS T
WHERE T.DIVISION = 'East';
```

EDIT 2: Currently the query returns :

```
<nba>
    <division ID="East">
        <player>
            <playerid>belinma01</playerid>
            <firstname>Marco</firstname>
            <lastname>Belinelli</lastname>
            <position>G</position>
            <points>469</points>
            <minutes>1121</minutes>
            <tindex>,25245316681534344335414808206958073149</tindex>
            <division>East</division>
            <teamid>TOR</teamid>
            <teamname>Toronto Raptors</teamname>
        </player>
        <!-- The same player 11 more times -->
    </division>
</nba>
```

What I want to return is:

```
<nba>
    <division ID="East">
        <player>
            <playerid></playerid>
            <firstname></firstname>
            <lastname></lastname>
            <position></position>
            <points></points>
            <minutes></minutes>
            <tindex></tindex>
            <division></division>
            <teamid></teamid>
            <teamname></teamname>
        </player>
        <!-- Top 12 in the East division -->
    </division>
    <division id="West>
        <!-- Top 12 in the west division -->
    </division>
</nba>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Show us the SQL/XML query you have tried

Comment: @imhotap edited the question to add it.

Comment: You say it "...does not return answers I want". Does it return incorrect data, or no data, or improperly formatted data, or something else? Some examples of what your input data looks like, what you expected the query to return, and what you got would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis eddited again.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're redefining `T` in your subquery for TEAMS.
   Instead of

   ```
   JOIN PLAYERS_TEAMS PT ON P.PLAYERID = PT.PLAYERID
   JOIN TEAMS T ON PT.TEAMID=T.TEAMID
   WHERE PT.YEAR=2009 AND T.DIVISION='East'
   ```

   you need to correlate the subquery with the outer/top-level query on
   TEAMS (bound to T):

   ```
   JOIN PLAYERS_TEAMS PT ON P.PLAYERID = PT.PLAYERID
   WHERE PT.YEAR=2009 AND T.DIVISION='East' AND PT.TEAMID = T.TEAMID
   ```
2. Using `ROWNUM` like that won't work; use an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to get the top 12 instead
3. You probably don't need `DISTINCT` here

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried that. The results remain the same.